# SQL join table with two 'ON' keyword?

Tags: mysql, join, database-connection

I have two tables tbl_a and tbl_b   and their fields are

```
tbl_a
-----
a_id a_name a_surname a_c_id a_d_id

tbl_b
-----
b_id b_name b_phone b_c_id b_d_id
```

I want to join these two table like this:

```
select *from tbl_a join tbl_b on tbl_a.a_c_id=tbl_b.b_c_id AND tbl_a.a_d_id=tbl_b.b_d_id where tbl_a.id>15;
```

As you can see i want to use two keys for ON keyword,is there anyway to do this?
Thanks for advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is right there is no need for putting extra On keyword 
AND keyword do work of join in on two different columns. Just put the bracket to understand properly.

```
select *from tbl_a join tbl_b on 
(
  tbl_a.a_c_id=tbl_b.b_c_id 
  AND 
  tbl_a.a_d_id=tbl_b.b_d_id 
)
where tbl_a.id>15;
```

Comment: Thanks it works!I want to ask something else,in tbl_a there are basically around hundred records but in tbl_b there hundred thousands records and it takes almost 120 seconds to execute it.Is it normal?I use dedicated server

Comment: I solved it there was logical error so it causes low performance.thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it should work fine.

In MySQL you can set multiple join constraints by using AND.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server allows this. I can speak for other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine but use alias instead of long tablename

```
select * from tbl_a a 
         join tbl_b b on a.a_c_id=b.b_c_id AND a.a_d_id=b.b_d_id 
         where a.id>15;
```